# How to select titles and price where price is more then price of 'Movie3'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table Movies.
How to select titles and price where price is more then price of 'Movie3' ?

For example:

```
Id |  Title  | Price
1  | Movie1  | 10
2  | Movie2  | 15
3  | Movie3  | 17
4  | Movie4  | 11
5  | Movie5  | 20
```

Result shuld be

```
Movie3 | 17
Movie5 | 20
```

I tried

```
select Title, Price from Movies
where Price > (select Price from Movies where Title = 'Movie3')
```

Comment: Your approach is correct but your operator is not. "`Result should be`" includes the "reference movie" so is-greater is wrong, is-greater-or-equal (`>=`) would be correct. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given price is of type int and title is varchar below will work

```
SELECT title,price FROM movies WHERE price >= (SELECT price FROM test WHERE title='Movie3')
```

Comment: can you explain "test", or is that a typo?

Comment: yeah sorry.. thats the table movies.. *typo*

Answer (score 2):

A "creative" solution without subselect:

```
SELECT Title, Price from Movies m1 
  INNER JOIN Movies m2 ON m1.Price >= m2.Price
  WHERE m2.Title LIKE "Movie3";
```

Note: This is more or equal to the price of movie3. in your question you were a bit unclear about this.